# trying to understand a macro definition in c

Tags: c, macros

This is a part of code that I'm trying to understand but I can't understand how a macro like this works. The first line `#define FOREACH_OMPD_STATE(macro)` defines a **function_like Macro** that has a parameter named '**macro**' but what does the rest of the definition mean?

```
#define FOREACH_OMPD_STATE(macro)                                             \
                                                                              \
    /* first available state */                                               \
    macro (ompt_state_undefined, 0x102)      /* undefined thread state */     \
                                                                              \
    /* work states (0..15) */                                                 \
    macro (ompt_state_work_serial, 0x000)    /* working outside parallel */   \
    macro (ompt_state_work_parallel, 0x001)  /* working within parallel */    \
    macro (ompt_state_work_reduction, 0x002) /* performing a reduction */
```

Are those different values for the parameter named **macro** or what?

Comment: The argument `macro` is the name of a macro that is applied with 4 different argument lists, presumably producing a useful result.  You'd have to see where `FOREACH_OMPD_STATE` is used to see more information about what those macro invocations do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FOREACH_OMPD_STATE` is an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). It provides a list that is used by passing various macros to do things with the list items. For example, we can use a macro that produces only the names to make a list of `enum` identifiers:

```
#define NameOnly(name, value)   name,

enum { FOREACH_OMPD_STATE(NameOnly) };
```

That code generates (line formatting added for readability):

```
enum {
    ompt_state_undefined,
    ompt_state_work_serial,
    ompt_state_work_parallel,
    ompt_state_work_reduction,
};
```

Having done that, we could use a different macro that creates array initializers to fill an array indexed by the `enum` identifiers with the values provided by the `FOREACH_OMPD_STATE` macro:

```
#define MakeInitializer(name, value)    [name] = value,

int ArrayOfValues[] = { FOREACH_OMPD_STATE(MakeInitializer) };
```

That generates (line formatting added for readability):

```
int ArrayOfValues = {
    [ompt_state_undefined] = 0x102,
    [ompt_state_work_serial] = 0x000,
    [ompt_state_work_parallel] = 0x001,
    [ompt_state_work_reduction] = 0x002,
};
```

The key idea is we only need to list the names and values once in the source code, in defining the `FOREACH_OMPD_STATE` macro, and then can use them in diverse ways later without repeating them.

Comment: A useful technique wherever lists of identifiers, possibly with associated values, are used, like token lists for languages etc. The number of parameters can be more than 2 if needed, and that way all information is only once assembled, centrally. You can stringize the preprocessor tokens which can be used for debug information that would otherwise only be available in languages with reflection. The central point is that no code must be touched at all when the list changes. Invaluable.